# Interacting programs stdin and stdout (create a robot program to play a game)

Tags: bash, process, pipe, c, fork

**The setup:**
I have an executable file, that I "cannot edit", since I don't have the source code. 
When I execute the program it reveals a game, where it hands me some numbers via `stdout`, for me to calculate, when I have done my calculation I can give my answer on `stdin` and it will tell rather I got the calculation right or not. Then I get a new calculation and it all repeats.

**The problem:** 
I could just manually play this game, but I would like to automate this with a program. The available tools on the system is `Bash` and a `C-compiler`.
What is the easiest way to interact with this program?

**What I have done so far:** 
I have been looking at pipes in `C`, and have a little program running where I fork the process and use pipes to communicate between the two processes. (something like this [program](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/c-program-demonstrate-fork-and-pipe/)). But I cannot get this to work when i call an external binary from the child process.

Comment: In what form are the questions? Do you have the standard `bc` utility available?

Comment: Here is an example of a question: the program gives you a date/time log `1970-05-05T15:32:32+0000` and you should parse it to the following format `Y-m-d H:M:S UTC`. The formats changes, so you should detect the format every time and parse it correctly.

Comment: `bc` is available.

Comment: Have you got `expect`?

Comment: @ctrl-alt-delor yes `expect` is available, but can dynamically use it to generate answers? I was of the impression that it was for a more static use.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using pipes and FIFO.

For example, here is my test script `blackbox.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Here i output the value to be added.
echo "10 30"

# Here i read the result and depending on it, write good or not good in a file
read result
if [ "${result}" -eq 40 ]; then
    echo good > result.txt
else
    echo not good > result.txt
fi
```

Ran manually:

```
$ ./blackbox.sh 
10 30 <~~~~ Script output
40 <~~~~~~~ My input
$ cat result.txt 
good
$
```

Now, i create a FIFO with `mkfifo coin` and run again with the following line:

```
$ rm result.txt && cat coin |./blackbox.sh | ( read a b ; echo $((a+b)) > coin )
$ cat result.txt 
good
```

Note that:

- Any write to the FIFO will block as long as it's not opened for reading.
- Piping the output of `blackbox.sh` to something will, obviously, make it invisible to you.
- I voluntary choose an simple example, where output of blackbox.sh is easy to parse... I let you adapt this to your need.
- `$(( ))` allow arithmetic in Bash.

Comment: I wonder how long it will take for someone to give `expect` as an answer.  (-:

Comment: @JdeBP We're just waiting for the OP to let us know what the questions from the program looks like.